# mysql UPDATE not working and not returning any errors

Tags: php, mysql

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET regstatus='TRUE' WHERE username='$id' AND regstring='$key'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0)
    header("refresh:3;url=login.php");
    echo "Your account is active now. Redirecting to login page."; }
```

I get an output Your account is active now. Redirecting to login page and redirects me to the login page.

But the value of `regstatus` is not being updated. As a part of debugging, I check mysql_num_rows on the query, and it says a row is affected, but the value doesnt get updated still.

Any ideas? the column regstatus is varchar.

Updated the code as per suggestions :

```
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET regstatus='True' WHERE username='$id' AND regstring='$key'") or
        die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($update)>0)
    {
        header("refresh:3;url=login.php");
        echo "Your account is active now. Redirecting to login page.";
    }
```

Now I get :

`Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /activate.php on line 27`

Comment: First check `if ($update)`; then why do you use `if (mysql_num_rows($check)`? What is `$check`?

Comment: Corrected. Please check the updated question again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
if (mysql_num_rows($update)>0) {
                    ^^^^^^     ^
```

Comment: @Kishor you havent corrected ... you replaced the function `mysql_num_rows` with `mysql_affected_rows` they take different arguments - either use `mysql_affected_rows` with your connection variable or `mysql_num_rows` with your result

Comment: Can you check now again now please?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `mysql_affected_rows()` instead of `mysql_num_rows()`. Also, the argument should be `$update` instead of `$check`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows():

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only
>   valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result
>   set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE,
>   REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

i.e. you have to use mysql_affected_rows in your code example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) for getting the number of affected rows for the `UPDATE` query.
You should also make clear what `$check` is.

In order to debug your MySQL query problem, try to debug print the query and to execute it manually, e.g. via PhpMyAdmin. Perhaps something is wrong with the parameters `$id` and `$key`.

Comment: Updated the question. I can see $id and $key has right values. But even if they have the wrong values, it should give the output without executing the actal query correctly. Wondering why.

Comment: Yes, that's because `mysql_num_rows` cannot get the number of affected rows for an `UPDATE` query. So, just replace `mysql_num_rows($update)` with `mysql_affected_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

what is "$check" in the statement

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0)
```

shouldnt that be "$update"?

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($update)>0)   {
```